# Python flask returns 405 error when using twitter api

Tags: python, api, flask, twitter, tweepy

I am using python and I apologize as this is probably a very simple concept that I am not grasping but I am not very familiar with the flask framework. Right now I'm making a server with flask but run into a 405 error every time I try to do something with the twitter api shortly after. Right now my code looks something like this

In a separate file:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def home():
    return "Hello world!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
  app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

Then I call my code in the main file:

```
from flaskfile import flask_file
flask_file()

MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json'
POST_TWEET_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'

CONSUMER_KEY = consumerkey
CONSUMER_SECRET = secret
ACCESS_TOKEN = accesstoken
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = tokensecret


#fileName = check_and_download()
VIDEO_FILENAME = (filename)


oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
  client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
  resource_owner_key=ACCESS_TOKEN,
  resource_owner_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)


class VideoTweet(object):

  def __init__(self, file_name):
    '''
    Defines video tweet properties
    '''
    self.video_filename = file_name
    self.total_bytes = os.path.getsize(self.video_filename)
    self.media_id = None
    self.processing_info = None


  def upload_init(self):
    '''
    Initializes Upload
    '''
    print('INIT')

    request_data = {
      'command': 'INIT',
      'media_type': 'video/mp4',
      'total_bytes': self.total_bytes,
      'media_category': 'tweet_video'
    }

    req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    media_id = req.json()['media_id']

    self.media_id = media_id

    print('Media ID: %s' % str(media_id))


  def upload_append(self):
    '''
    Uploads media in chunks and appends to chunks uploaded
    '''
    segment_id = 0
    bytes_sent = 0
    file = open(self.video_filename, 'rb')

    while bytes_sent < self.total_bytes:
      chunk = file.read(4*1024*1024)
      
      print('APPEND')

      request_data = {
        'command': 'APPEND',
        'media_id': self.media_id,
        'segment_index': segment_id
      }

      files = {
        'media':chunk
      }

      req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, files=files, auth=oauth)

      if req.status_code < 200 or req.status_code > 299:
        print(req.status_code)
        print(req.text)
        sys.exit(0)

      segment_id = segment_id + 1
      bytes_sent = file.tell()

      print('%s of %s bytes uploaded' % (str(bytes_sent), str(self.total_bytes)))

    print('Upload chunks complete.')


  def upload_finalize(self):
    '''
    Finalizes uploads and starts video processing
    '''
    print('FINALIZE')

    request_data = {
      'command': 'FINALIZE',
      'media_id': self.media_id
    }

    req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    print(req.json())

    self.processing_info = req.json().get('processing_info', None)
    self.check_status()


  def check_status(self):
    '''
    Checks video processing status
    '''
    if self.processing_info is None:
      return

    state = self.processing_info['state']

    print('Media processing status is %s ' % state)

    if state == u'succeeded':
      return

    if state == u'failed':
      sys.exit(0)

    check_after_secs = self.processing_info['check_after_secs']
    
    print('Checking after %s seconds' % str(check_after_secs))
    time.sleep(check_after_secs)

    print('STATUS')

    request_params = {
      'command': 'STATUS',
      'media_id': self.media_id
    }

    req = requests.get(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, params=request_params, auth=oauth)
    
    self.processing_info = req.json().get('processing_info', None)
    self.check_status()


  def tweet(self):
    '''
    Publishes Tweet with attached video
    '''
    request_data = {
        #leave status blank
      'status': '',
      'media_ids': self.media_id
    }

    req = requests.post(url=POST_TWEET_URL, data=request_data, auth=oauth)
    print(req.json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  videoTweet = VideoTweet(VIDEO_FILENAME)
  videoTweet.upload_init()
  videoTweet.upload_append()
  videoTweet.upload_finalize()
  videoTweet.tweet()
```

The error returned states the following:

"Error response

Error code: 405

Message: Method Not Allowed.

Error code explanation: 405 - Specified method is invalid for this resource."

Basically I call the flask file then use twitter api to upload a file, but for some reason using the twitter api always results in a 405 error and my flask server is no longer accessible. How can I adjust my flask file to allow me to upload using the api?

Answer (score 0):

405 errors are thrown when the wrong request method is used. For example a POST request being sent when a GET request was expected, or a GET request being sent when a POST request was expected.

In your `check_status` function you have

```
req = requests.get(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, ...
```

But according to [Twitter's documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload) you should be using a post request here

```
req = requests.post(url=MEDIA_ENDPOINT_URL, ...
```

Comment: still seem to be getting the 405 error, even when using .post instead of .get